# REGEX is not working for RPM

Tags: perl

```
perl-Class-Std-Utils-0.0.3-1.el4.rf
```

how to extract the values :perl-Class-Std-Utils and 0.0.3-1

```
$aad='perl-Class-Std-Utils-0.0.3-1.el4.rf';

if ( $aad =~ /(^[\w+-]-(\d*)\.(.*))/{
    print " $1 = $2 = $3 " ;
}
```

it not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a slightly different version (no big difference to M42's suggestion though):

```
my $aad='perl-Class-Std-Utils-0.0.3-1.el4.rf';

if ($aad =~ m/^([\w-]+)-([\d.-]+)\.([\w.]+)$/) {
   print "$1 = $2 = $3\n";
}
```

Which prints

```
perl-Class-Std-Utils = 0.0.3-1 = el4.rf
```

You had a `+` inside your first character class; I suspected it might have been meant as a quantifier instead of as the '+' character. Consequently, I removed it, as you cannot use quantifiers within character classes, but, of course, I may have misread your intentions entirely.

Furthermore, I got rid of the `(.*)` bit - best be as specific as you can if you know what it is you want to match.

Answer (score 0):

Have a try with:

```
my $aad='perl-Class-Std-Utils-0.0.3-1.el4.rf';

if ( $aad =~ /^([\w+-]+)-([\d.-]+)\.(.*)/) {
    print " $1 = $2 = $3 " ;
}
```

**Ouptput:**

```
perl-Class-Std-Utils = 0.0.3-1 = el4.rf
```